# Find all UserControls of a certain type on a page, possibly using LINQ?

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls

I have created a base user control (BaseUserControl) class that is implemented by all my user controls. In that class I have a property that contains a collection of JavaScript URL references.  What is the best way to parse a page for that type of user control?

I experimented using LINQ, but I don’t think I can query the Controls collection with it:

```
var controls = (from c in page.Controls where c is BaseUserControl)
foreach(control in controls){
     var javascript = control.JavaScriptReference
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The slightly more idiomatic way to do that would be to use [Enumerable.OfType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360913.aspx).

```
foreach(var control in page.Controls.OfType<BaseUserControl>()) {
     var javascript = control.JavaScriptReference;
}
```

Comment: oops... you beat me to it :) +1

Comment: beat me too! I just found this while messing with the the LINQ expression.

Comment: I wasn't aware of OfType(). Nice!

Answer (score 3):

```
var javascript = page.Controls.OfType<BaseUserControl>().Select(c=> c.JavaScriptReference);
```

That should work.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want a collection of JavaScriptReference values, you could do something like:

```
var javascriptReferences = page.Controls.Where(c => c is BaseUserControl)
                                        .Select(c => c.JavaScriptReference);
```

Answer (score 1):

I use a recursive approach to this issue. See below the method that I normally use.

```
private void GetControls<T>(Control ctrl, List<T> result)
{
    foreach (Control con in ctrl.Controls.OfType<Control>().Where(c => c.Controls.Count > 0))
        GetControls<T>(con, result);
    foreach (T control in ctrl.Controls.OfType<T>())
        result.Add(control);
}
```

You can call it like this:

```
List<BaseUserControl> baseUserControls = new List<BaseUserControl>();
GetControls<BaseUserControl>(Page.Controls, out baseUserControl);
```

After that the List is filled with references to your BaseUserControls. The recursive approach is necessary because `Page.Controls` does not contain all controls on your page. Some controls on your page are children of a control that is in this collection (or even children of those) and are thus nested levels deeper. Hence recursive approach.

Answer (score 0):

Did you correctly select the control?

```
var controls = (from c in page.Controls where c is BaseUserControl select c)
foreach(BaseUserControl control in controls)
{     
var javascript = control.JavaScriptReference
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach (var control in
       page.Controls.OfType<BaseUserControl>())
{
       var javascript = control.JavaScriptReference;
}
```